# How to convert label text to speech

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder4.5

I need to create an application which reads the text from a label, and when user clicks the play button, it will speak label text. I am currently using flash builder 4.5.

Does anyone have any idea how to work with that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reading text from a label"? Do you mean recognizing text on photo or just getting it from text input field?

Comment: Hello, I want to develop functionality like "read label text and convert into voice dynamically"

Answer (score 0):

get the text to speech api key and software from  https://www.ispeech.org/developers/flash
then make http requests like http://www.ispeech.org/api/

get text with `label.text`